# PL/SQL tasks with procedure and trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, procedure

I am currently learning PL/SQL and have some tasks to be solved and have no clue how to do them.
I have the following tables:

```
create table Student (
  id_stud number (10) not null,
  name varchar2 (30),
  PRIMARY KEY (id_stud)
);

create table lecture (
  id_l number (10) not null,
  titel varchar2 (40),
  PRIMARY KEY (id_l)
);

create table seminar (
  id_seminar number (10) not null,
  description varchar2 (30),
  id_l number (10) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_seminar),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_l) REFERENCES lecture (id_l)
);

create Table participate_student_lecture(
  id_stud number (10) not null,
  id_l number (10) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_stud , id_l ),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_stud ) REFERENCES Student(id_stud ),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_l ) REFERENCES lecture(id_l )
);

create table participate_student_seminar (
  id_stud number (10) not null,
  id_seminar number (10) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_stud , id_seminar ),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_stud ) REFERENCES Student(id_stud ),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_seminar ) REFERENCES seminar(id_seminar )
);
```

and the following tasks:

- A procedure should delete lectures and the associated seminars. It has to be only possible if there is no student registered in the lecture or in the seminar. If the lecture cannot be deleted, a message should be thrown.
- A procedure should delete seminars, but only if there is no student registered in this seminar.
- When students register for seminars, the student should automatically also be registered for the corresponding lecture. -> solve with trigger
- If there are several seminars available for a lecture (a lecture can have 1-3 seminars), they should be filled equaly. That means that the students should alternately be assigned to the seminars. (Student 1 seminar 1, student 2 seminar 2, student 3 seminar 3, student 4 seminar 1) -> solve with trigger

Do you have some solutions for me or at least some hints?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Also you should ask one question per question, because questions should be focused to be reused by others.

Comment: If you are taking a class somewhere, you should use the class resources to get you started, rather than posting for help. We don't know the context of your class. Once you do get some help, it would be great if you would follow up with a post explaining how you solved ONE of your challenges, so others can learn how to solve problems on their own,... which is what you really want to learn, right? How to solve problems on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I will see if I can point you is the right direction, and provide some basic suggestions. First, not directly related but something I stress: The time to start forming good habits is while you are learning. A couple examples here:

1. Use descriptive names. This is mostly good on here but `id_l`? Is that really descriptive. Maybe here with 4 tables, but how about with 40 or 400 tables.
2. Take the time to Name your constraints. If you do not Oracle will, but I assure you that you do not want to work with Oracle generated names; See [Example1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4c4013e8be9130eff6a5c593a272559) vs [Example2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a62a1b3ffe83f4975c8860b100eb2b6b). They are identical except for naming he constraints. Take a look at the last statement and the error message. Which of these would you prefer to have trace down. (Ignore the part beginning `FIDDLE_... up to the single dot (.) separator.  This is the db<>fiddle generated schema name, you will see schema name that owns the constraint.)
3. Keep your procedures as simple as possible to complete a single task.

Now to your issue directly:  
Your first two bullet points are handled by the examples above. There I just changed the FK on `seminar to lecture` to include  [on delete cascade](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-foreign-key/) . This causes Oracle to attempt deleting all `Seminar` associated to the specified `lecture`. Do not put the on delete cascade of the FK from `participate_student_seminar` to `seminar`. Now when Oracle attempts to delete a similar having participating students that FK will cause an exception (whether the delete is a result of direct delete or cascade from lecture.  

Your third point is the one with the most drastic change. It says *solve with trigger*, I hope this is your thought and not a requirement. It is a very bad solution. I will assume it is  not a requirement. My solution **do not do anything**, well at least at run time. It is fully derivable  by joining `participate_student_seminar` and and `seminar`. So Drop the table `participate_student_lecture` and recreate it as a VIEW. [Example3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=654aa8f77413d928775592cfce0978b6)  

Your last point (also hope a trigger is not required). Would be the most difficult. Tracking a round-robin-assignment typically would require tracking the last assigned. But even so it would not necessarily accomplish the goal of "filled equally". It appears as a student is permitted to register for a particular seminar (3rd bullet point). So what happens when several do and request the same seminar. Perhaps a better approach would be count the registrations and make the assignment to the one with the lowest number. This comes closer to the goal although not assigning student1 to seminar1, student2 to seminar2 ... Something like:

```
insert into participate_student_seminar_3( id_student, id_seminar)
select &student_id, id_seminar
  from (select ls.id_seminar,  count(*)  
          from  participate_student_seminar_3 pss
          join  seminar_3 ls on(pss.id_seminar = ls.id_seminar) 
         where  ls.id_lecture = &lecture_id
         group by  ls.id_seminar
         order by  count(*), ls.id_seminar   
        ) 
 fetch first 1 row only;
```

I'll leave it to you to put this altogether into procedures. Hint: do not try just a single procedure. Yes it can be done, but then the procedure has multiple tasks to perform. At least use 2 for Inserting another for Deleting. Deleting should be simple. Let me know if you have problems and can show me some code indicating your specific issue.